# How to obtain the last item of an array from BehaviorSubject<any[]>

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, typescript-typings

I have an Array that changes based on behaviourSubject

I want to access the last item of that array

`this.projectList[this.projectList.length -1]`

But when i try to do it i find this error.

`No index signature with a parameter of type 'number' was found on type 'BehaviorSubject<any[]>`

How can I access that array to retrieve the last index?

Comment: From the error, you're trying to access directly the `BehaviourSubject`, not the array. What's exactly `projectList`, an array or a `BehaviourSubject`? And what do you exactly mean by "an Array that changes based on behaviourSubject"? Is the array emitted by the `BehaviourSubject`?

Comment: What library is `BehaviourSubject` coming from? Also don't use `any`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to access an array emitted by your `BehaviourSubject` and `projectList` is the `BehaviourSubject` (not the array), you can access the last emitted value like this:

```
const lastEmittedArray = this.projectList.value;
```

Then you get the last item: `lastEmittedArray[lastEmittedArray.length - 1]`

Comment: thanks, with that I was able to access the data I wanted

Answer (score 0):

```
this.projectList.pipe(
   map(projectList => projectList[projectList.length - 1])
)
```

The above will return another Observable of type Observable